# maven compilation error while running tests it says: use -source 8 or higher to enable static interface methods

Tags: maven-3, testng

I am using JDK 8 because when I use **mvn --version** it gives:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T22:29:23+05:00)

Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.5
Java version: 1.8.0_11, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
```

OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-32-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

So why it is saying to me:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.598 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-05T16:58:05+05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/88M
[INFO]     ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-    plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project string-format-    validators: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/affan/Development/NetBeansProjects/reference-artifacts-repository/javase/string-format-validators/src/main/java/str/frmt/validators/FactoryInterface.java:[7,37] static interface methods are not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 8 or higher to enable static interface methods)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

when I am running test with ***mvn test***

Answer (score 1):

**It looks like you manually set Java version for some module to 7**. Look at all maven compiler plugin configurations.